# Drupal 8 translating paragraphs programmatically

Tags: drupal, translation, paragraphs

Paragraphs are supposed to be translated on on the level of their component fields, not on the paragraph_field level. So how do you programmatically translate paragraphs?

To be more explicit, my paragraph field is not translatable, but the component fields are. So how can I load a node, loop through the paragraph items, and add translations to the fields?

Does anyone have an example? 
Thanks.

Comment: For programmatically translating, you need to use some third party service, like google translate, etc... please refer to individual documentation, which service is suitable for you

Comment: no, that totally misses the point of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/translate-programmatically-drupal-8 node translation:

This is an abstraction of my actual code, and I haven't actually tested it:

```
$node = node_load(12);

if ($node->hasTranslation('de')) {
  $transl_node = $node->getTranslation('de');

  foreach ($transl_node->field_paragraph  => $paragraph) {
      $entity_array = $paragraph->toArray();
      $translated_fields = [];
        $translated_fields['field_body'] = array(
          'value' => 'translated value',
          'format' => 'full'
        );
        $translated_fields['field_section_title'] = 'translated section title';

        $translated_entity_array = array_merge($entity_array, $translated_fields);
        if (!$paragraph->hasTranslation('de')) {
          $paragraph->addTranslation('de', $translated_entity_array);
          $paragraph->save();
        }
  }
  $transl_node->save();
}
```